# C# form auto resize window

Tags: c#, winforms, window, autoresize

I have a form app. inside I have a richTextBox. How to make make the app to auto resize the rich textBOx? meaning if I expand or max the window, rich textBox should follow

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use your TextBox's [Anchor property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx). You'll probably want to set it to all sides, Top, Bottom, Left, Right.

Comment: I have a progress bar under the richTextBox. how to handle this? I can't use the anchor

Comment: First, set your ProgressBar's Anchor to Bottom, Left, Right. Then place your RichTextBox above it, and Anchor it on all 4 sides.

Answer (score 5):

If the `RichTextBox` is the only control you can set it's `Dock` property to `Fill`. If it shares the form with other controls you can use the `Anchor` property.

If you need more help with GUI layout in Visual Studio see 
[Designing Resizable Windows Forms in Visual Studio .NET](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/6964/0/page/1).